# Android Studio build fails on every other try

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I downloaded latest Android Studio 0.2.2. Created a new project, upgraded to release 0.2.3.

1. First time I hit the run button the build fails:

   org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation
    'C:\Users\jblack.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.6-bin\72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok\gradle-1.6' ...
2. Hit the run button again (no changes made), the build succeeds and the application runs.
3. Hit the run button again, same error as before.

I've had many problems with the build system - this is the first time I've been able to identify any sort of pattern.

Any ideas?

---

A system reboot and restarting Android Studio seems to have fixed the above problem.

I suspect the problems starts when the Gradle daemon dies.

---

I keep running into this problem. The edit, build, run cycle works fine for a while and then Android Studio gets into the state where every other build fails (sometime every build fails). Usually exiting and restarting Android Studio temporarily cures the problem.

Even though I can work around the problem, it is a major pain.

Comment: I am running into a similar problem without using an IDE.  My daemons sometimes die and every other build fails.  I think they are dieing due to out of memory/perm gen problems. If you run gradle --stop using the same gradle jar that Android Studio is relying on to run daemons, that should force the IDE to start a new daemon the next time the build runs.  Temporary fix, but maybe it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a workaround:

1. install gradle 1.8 RC (only binaries) from gradle.org into C:\Gradle,
2. specify this folder in preferences

this works for me.